# Azure Functions support for authentication with HTTP trigger running in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

Using the built in App Service Authentication / Authorization to populate the ClaimsPrincipal when hosting functions in Azure works great and is pretty well documented.

However, trying to accomplish this with a containerized app in Kubernetes is a different story. I can't find any information on how to support authentication in a way that would mimic the behavior of hosting the functions in Azure. I hope this is possible because I would like to use the same functions both on-premises and in Azure.

Is there any information available on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

App Service Authentication / Authorization is a feature provided as part of the PAAS offering. The [Azure Functions Host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host), which is open-source, inherits such features when running on Azure PAAS.

But when running on kubernetes, the way Azure Functions works is different. For one, scaling is taken care of kubernetes (and [knative](https://knative.dev/)/[osiris](https://github.com/deislabs/osiris)/[keda](https://keda.sh/) when setup). The same goes for any external authentication/authorization.

There are a couple of ways you could set this up

1. If you are using an ingress controller like nginx, you can pair it with oauth2_proxy for [external oauth authentication](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth). Depending on the ingress controller you are using, it may have built-in support for authentication.
2. If you are using a service mesh like istio, you could make use of its [end-user authentication](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication) policies. Note that this just checks if there is a valid JWT and doesn't redirect users.

   You would have to deploy an [EnvoyFilter](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) similar to [this one](https://gist.github.com/suman-ganta/27393c829521d2a68996137dd1024084#file-envoy-filter-yaml). For an SSO scenario, you might need [something like this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/8619#issuecomment-503468943).

Comment: I can definitely use an external authentication service to deal with the actual authentication but what I want is some way to initialize the ClaimsPrincipal passed to the functions so that my existing authorization code in the functions continues to work.